# process records in specific order

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 2 tables. One is orders we need to ship. There is a date to ship by, part numbers, and quantities needed, and an order # (among other fields). A second table contains parts on order from vendors. It has Purchase Order #'s, quantities, and part numbers.

What I need to be able to do is process the order table in VBA in a specific order. It needs to be "sorted" by ship by date (oldest date first), then by order number. I have code (below) that adds the PO # to the order table so I can see what PO my needed items are on. The problem is the code does not take into consideration the order I want it processed in. I have come to understand that tables are not spreadsheets and that order is not something I am guaranteed.

What do I need to do to be able to process this in the order specified. I've included my code below which does work fine OTHER than not processing in the order requested.

```
Public Sub Magic()

Dim SOQi As Integer
Dim POQi As Integer
Dim PONi As Long

Dim db As Database
Dim SOrs As Recordset
Dim POrs As Recordset2

Set db = CurrentDb
Set SOrs = db.OpenRecordset("T_openorders")
Set POrs = db.OpenRecordset("T_InboundPO")

SOrs.MoveFirst
Do Until SOrs.EOF
    If SOrs.Fields("missing") < 0 Then
    POrs.MoveFirst
        Do Until POrs.EOF
           SOQi = SOrs.Fields("missing")
                If POrs.Fields("OrderQty") > 0 Then
                        POQi = POrs.Fields("OrderQty")
                        If POrs.Fields("PartNum") = SOrs.Fields("PartNum") Then
                            If Abs(POQi) > Abs(SOQi) Then
                                POQi = POQi + SOQi
                                PONi = POrs.Fields("PONUM")
                                POrs.Edit
                                POrs("OrderQty") = POQi
                                POrs.Update
                                SOrs.Edit
                                SOrs("PONum") = PONi
                                SOrs("missing") = 0
                                SOrs.Update
                             Else
                                SOQi = POQi + SOQi
                                PONi = POrs.Fields("PONUM")
                                POrs.Edit
                                POrs("OrderQty") = 0
                                POrs.Update
                                SOrs.Edit
                                SOrs("PONum") = PONi
                                SOrs("missing") = SOQi
                                SOrs.Update
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
            POrs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
SOrs.MoveNext
Loop



SOrs.Close

Set SOrs = Nothing
Set POrs = Nothing
db.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `SELECT` query as your recordset's data source.  In the query, you can include an `ORDER BY` clause, and the records will be loaded into the recordset in that order.

I lost track of your table and field names, so made up my own.

```vb
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSelect As String

strSelect = "SELECT y.* FROM YourTable AS y" & vbCrLf & _
    "ORDER BY y.[ship by date], y.[order number];"
Debug.Print strSelect

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSelect)
' loop through the recordset row to confirm
' data is present in correct order ...
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs![ship by date], rs![order number]
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: In doing this, will I still be able to update the actual tables with the data I'm manipulating?

Comment: Test your `SELECT` as a new query in the Access query designer.  If its result set is editable, the recordset based on that same `SELECT` should be editable, too.